# Erro relacionado ao CSS global ao executar projeto

Tags: react, next.js

Tenho outros dois projetos com a mesma estrutura de arquivos e que estão executando (npm run dev) normalmente porém este terceiro termina em erro e não renderiza a página padrão de um projeto com next.js.

Failed to compile
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom . Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: src\pages_app.js

Segue imagem ilustrando a estrutura dos arquivos...[image: Estrutura de Arquivos]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Minha questão é como resolver o erro mencionado que reclama da importação do arquivo de CSS global.

Anexei uma imagem demonstrando toda a estrutura de arquivos, assim como a linha em que o arquivo CSS global é importado.

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se é o seu caso, mas aparentemente o ReactJS tem alguns problemas em questões de nomeclaturas de caminhos.
***Qualquer caractere especial, inclusive acentos e espaços podem dificultar e gerar este problema.***
Como o NextJS deriva do ReactJS, deve ter herdado esta característica um pouco irritante. Me deparei com este erro recentemente pois no caminho continha uma pasta iniciada com `#` jogo-da-velha e me atentei devido uma história do mestrado do meu professor, que passou um dia inteiro procurando o problema que era o acento do nome dele no direetório '-'